# Building Flex 3 Project from MSBuild

Tags: apache-flex, msbuild, flex3, build-process

I am working on a .NET project with a Flex/Flash front end. The build scripts are written in MSBuild and I'm looking to build the Flex project (authored in Flex Builder 3) from my primary build script.

**What options do I have for building a Flex 3 application from MSBuild?**

I've already seen [flexbuild](http://code.google.com/p/flexbuild), and it looked ideal until I tried it. I get the same error as [reported](http://code.google.com/p/flexbuild/issues/detail?id=1) by others and the project looks kind of . . . dead.

Note that I really want to minimize the complexity of my build. If possible, I don't want to have to shell out to Ant.

EDIT: having downloaded and examined the source of flexbuild, I see that it is looking for Eclipse projects that do not exist. I guess there is a difference between the project files of Flex Builder 3 and Eclipse. I need to get this working with FB3 though - Eclipse isn't an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find using a simple batch file works just fine.

Here, where %FLEXSDK% contains the path to the SDK you're using, %DEBUG% "true" or "false", and %OUTPUT_PATH% the destination path and filename:

```
"%FLEXSDK%\bin\mxmlc" -debug=%DEBUG% -output=%OUTPUT_PATH% src\MyMain.mxml
```

Simple and straightforward!  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This may work for simple projects but ours has dependencies so this fails to build. I guess I could play around with compiler options like compiler.library-path but then I need to keep the project file in sync with the build script.

Comment: It's definitely worth exploring, yeah.  I simplified my command line for purposes of illustration, but we build pretty much exactly this way, with mxmlc, the SDK and a flex-config.xml file, and all goes well -- localization, modules, etc., all get handled with a single batch file.  Good luck!

Comment: As I feared, I was able to get this building but there are already discrepancies between my output and that of FB3. I don't like the idea of manually keeping the build script in sync with the project file(s), so I think we'll be checking in the Flex binaries until I can figure out a better solution. It may be that I either replicate the Ant tasks as MSBuild tasks, or I shell out to Ant.